# Is there a JDO method analogous to the low-level App Engine Datastore API method get(Iterable<Key> keys)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I want to get multiple entities from the App Engine datastore by passing a list of keys as the parameter. The low level API has a method for this: get(Iterable keys). Is there an analogous method available for the JDO interface as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try PersistenceManager.getObjectsById(Collection... keys)